# Import "matplotlib" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pylance

whenever I try to import matplotlib or matplotlib.pyplot in VS Code I get the error in the title:

```
Import "matplotlib" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)
```

or

```
Import "matplotlib.pyplot" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)
```

The hyperlink of the reportMissingModuleSource sends me to https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md#diagnostic-severity-rules, where it says:
*"Diagnostics for imports that have no corresponding source file. This happens when a type stub is found, but the module source file was not found, indicating that the code may fail at runtime when using this execution environment. Type checking will be done using the type stub."*
However, from the explanation I don't understand exactly what's wrong and what I should do to fix this, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Thanks for the answers - but I have the same problem and you suggestion doesn't help for me.
Everything was fine under Python 3.6 but I have just upgraded to 3.10 and now I can't seem to reference matplotlib at all. Same error as yours.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can reproduce your question when I select a python interpreter where doesn't exist `matplotlib`:

[image]

So, the solution is opening an **integrated** Terminal then run `pip install matplotlib`. After it's installed successfully, please **reload window**, then the warning should go away.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Sometimes it's back to multiple versions of python on your device. You just need to change the path. Make sure the correct Python interpreter is selected in your IDE.

In `vscode` Press `CTRL + Shift + P` or (`⌘ + Shift + P` on macOS) to open the command palette. Then type `Python select interpreter` in the search field and choose the right version.

Answer (score 2):

Just changes the interpreter to 2.7.x in left-bottom corner [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0INoe.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar issue even after installing **vs_BuildTools**.

[Matplotlib could not be resolved from source parlance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2BgW.jpg)

What to do:

1. open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)
2. Type: **Python: Select interpreter** [Here is the interpreter that worked for me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1trIU.jpg)
3. Navigate to your project.
4. Select the latest interpreter or check what interpreter

Answer (score 1):

VSCode terminal does not activate your venv right after it is created. You might have installed the package to your computer instead of venv you use.

Try close VSCode terminal and repoen. Virtual environment might be active and try to install the package again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue - I did two things and its working now

- Check if there is some earlier versions of python installed on your machine - if yes then remove and reinstall the latest one
- Second install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools
  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Restart the app and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem and realised the package install path for my active virtual env wasn't listed in sys.path
after appending this location to sys.path my .ipynb was able to import matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

Check this part and change it to correct interpreter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6OI1.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).