# i cant import 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib

i'm trying to make an ai that can go from celcius to farenheit and i can't import "matplotlib.pyplot" even though i have it installed. Is there any way to fix it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel("# Epoca")
plt.ylabel("magnitud perdida")
plt.plot(historial.history["loss"])

error:import matplotlib.pyplot could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)
```

I tried to see if I had it installed and indeed it was, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow for existing solutions, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/70709406/9987623?

Comment: You must used the virtual environment,but you do not know you use it.Not install `matplotlib` directly in `CMD` if you use pycharm or other IDE.

Comment: What IDE are you using?